# GWT-Youtube-API no source code available for YouTubeEmbeddedPlayer

Tags: gwt, youtube, youtube-api

I tried to embed a Video in my GWT Project but I get the following error in my console when I open the panel containing the video:

```
No source code is available for type com.google.youtube.client.YouTubeEmbeddedPlayer; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

[My Build Path for the Project](http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/f2f0hnqs/Selection_003.jpeg)

And this is the example code

```
    YouTubeEmbeddedPlayer youTubeEmbeddedPlayer = new YouTubeEmbeddedPlayer("hqXUKxJiDls");
    youTubeEmbeddedPlayer.setWidth("427px");
    youTubeEmbeddedPlayer.setHeight("320px");
    absolutePanel.add(youTubeEmbeddedPlayer, 200, 30);
```

project.gwt.xml:

```
    <inherits name="com.google.gdata.YouTubeAPI" />
    <inherits name="com.google.youtube.Player" />
```

I followed the GettingStarted wiki entry but I don't know where to put the settings.xml (it's not explained).

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding *gwt-youtube-api-1.0.3-sources.jar* to your classpath as a standard library instead of adding it as a source attachment for *gwt-youtube-api-1.0.3.jar*.