# Gwt youtube data api v3

Tags: java, xml, gwt, youtube, youtube-data-api

i'm usin a jar "/TestYoutube/.google_apis/youtube-v3r102lv1.16.0-rc/youtube/google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev102-1.16.0-rc.jar", i added in the build path and the imports works perfectly ("import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ResourceId;").

But i'm trying to launch, and it says that in my browser:

```
    Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997
    Follow the troubleshooting instructions at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM
```

And my development mode:

```
    [TRACE] [testyoutube] - Finding entry point classes
[ERROR] [testyoutube] - Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/Alejandro/workspace%20java/TestYoutube/src/aiss/client/TestYoutube.java'
    [ERROR] [testyoutube] - Line 103: No source code is available for type com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Then i googled and i see that i have to put a module in TestYoutube.gwt.xml:

```
<inherit name="com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult"/>
```

But now my console say me:

```
    Loading modules


aiss.TestYoutube
      Loading inherited module 'aiss.TestYoutube'
         [ERROR] Line 18: Unexpected element 'inherit'
         [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onUnexpectedElement(DefaultSchema.java:86)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onUnexpectedElement(Schema.java:94)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onUnexpectedElement(Schema.java:94)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:223)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
         [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:371)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

Sorry, my english is very bad and i don't know what i'm doing bad....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is clear from logs.

```
[ERROR] Line 18: Unexpected element 'inherit'
[ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
```

use `inherits` instead of `inherit`.

Please have a look at [gwt-module.dtd](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd).

---

Go to your `TestYoutube.gwt.xml` file and try with below line.

```
<inherits name="com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult"/>
```

Comment: I did it but now say me:[ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/api/services/youtube/model/SearchResult.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

[ERROR] Line 18: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'

Comment: Please confirm you have added required jar in your project's classpath.

Comment: I don't know why eclipse is searching a xml if is only a class from a jar... (i don't have any folder "com/google/api/services/youtube/model" in my project and i haven't a xml called SearchResult.gwt.xml)

Comment: Good catch, now you are going in right direction i.e it's an invalid entry in gwt.xml. There must be a different module that needs to be inherited let me find it out.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `SearchResult.gwt.xml` file in your `google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev102-1.16.0-rc.jar`?

Comment: I have all jars in Youtube Data Api (http://i59.tinypic.com/mrs421.jpg) but i didn't do any xml

Comment: please have a look at [GWT-Youtube-API no source code available for YouTubeEmbeddedPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309072/gwt-youtube-api-no-source-code-available-for-youtubeembeddedplayer)

Comment: Add `<inherits name="com.google.gdata.YouTubeAPI">` in gwt.xml. Please have a look at [http://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/wiki/GettingStarted](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: Please have a look at [No source code is available for YouTubeEmbeddedPlayer](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/issues/detail?id=4)

Comment: Now say me: "Unable to find YouTubeAPI.gwt.xml" http://i62.tinypic.com/250o5xd.jpg (i forget put in <inherits> a / but nothing happend)

Comment: I go to add all dependencies but I don't know how I can add repositories on eclipse...

Comment: Have you read all the links that I have shared because I can't set up GWT Youtube API on my system due to slow network.

Comment: I go to read all again, but my english is very bad and I dont understand everything :(

Comment: In http://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/wiki/GettingStarted I did the 1 and 2 steps but i don't know how can I do in eclipse... My project is in GWT, not in maven and I think that step 3 is for maven

Comment: Have you added all the jars in class-path that is mentioned in step-2?

Comment: When i add all jars from https://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/issues/detail?id=4 i allways get a Http Error: 503

Comment: I am talking about jars mentioned at step 2 at [http://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/wiki/GettingStarted](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: Yes, I added all jars but in other page (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/issues/detail?id=4) have 1 source more and gwt-math... but nothing works